# MS Access column-level security

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I need to be able to restrict access to a specific columns in my database.
The user cannot make a SQL view of columns A and D or C and D but are allowed to for B and D.

Any suggestions and help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Access Database Engine is not designed to manage security in the way that you have described<sup>*</sup>. You could restrict access to certain items at the application level, but users would still be able to open the back-end database file directly and see things that you apparently don't want them to see.

If this sort of security really is important then you should use a client/server back-end database and set permissions on various objects at the database level. For example, any edition of Microsoft SQL Server, even the Express Edition, can do this.

<sup>*</sup>(The older Access `.mdb` database format supported user-level security, but that security model has been deprecated.)

Answer (score 0):

As a general approach for relational databases, I would just suggest a view creation (which would contain only columns available for particular users) and then just allowing access to the views and forbidding access to the tables.